# How can I render a page and generate metadata with just once api request?

Tags: next.js14

```js
// app/page.js
export async function generateMetadata({ params, searchParams }, parent) {
    const info = await getContentInfo({ id: params.id, language: params.language });
    return {
        title: info.name,
    };
}

export default async function Home({ params }) {
    const info = await getContentInfo({ id: params.id, language: params.language });
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{info.name}</h1>
            {HTMLReactParser(info.content)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

How can I render a page and generate metadata with just once api request?

Answer (score 0):

you can't it is a separate function that is exported .

but it doesn't really matter if you do it in one request or two.

Fetch requests are automatically cached unless you specify not to,
so basically you are doing one call to your api and the second one is from cache.

even in vercel hosting
you can see outgoing request and what is cached

Comment: I custom the fetch function, and put params in options.body. So, my request will not be cached.Yestody, I read a blog which vercel post, about cache. I find that i need to put the params in url,likes: www.api.com/api?a=1&b=2.